# Running Mac OS X on Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have my workstation setup with a Windows Server 2008 running Hyper-V.
Now I really want to install OS X for testing purposes.

Have anyone had any success running Mac OS X in an Hyper-V environment?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to check questions http://serverfault.com/questions/4046/virtualizing-os-x and http://serverfault.com/questions/3665/how-to-run-os-x-leopard-or-tiger-in-windows as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, Mac OS X (or at least leopard) will not work on a virtual machine without heavy modifications. One attempt was "released" illegally [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090418060259/http://pcwizcomputer.com/index.php?Itemid=45&id=75&option=com_content&task=view) (no links to actual copyrighted files included).

Mac OS X's architecture is different and requires EFI emulation among other stuff.

In addition, I believe it's against the EULA to run Mac OS X on anything but apple hardware (antitrust anyone?).

Comment: Correct on all points but there are VMWare VM's 'out there' in bittorrent-land to be had that do work fine on VMWare. No idea if it'll work on HV though.

Comment: "work fine" as in really really ... really really slow, since there are no "VMware tools" drivers available. I believe those VMs are actually what I noted on the link, and are heavily modified version of Leopard.

Comment: It should be additionally noted that only Mac OS X *Server* 10.5 and later is permitted to be virtualized per the EULA.

Comment: @LiraNuna: Not true, there are vmware tools for OS X. It's packaged with VMware Fusion (a Mac product).

Comment: @bahamat: This was written in 2009.

Comment: @LiraNuna: Ah, I didn't look at the date. I guess it's more appropriate to say "no longer true". I'd update my comment if it were still editable.

Answer (score 3):

The only virtual environment Mac OS X works on is... Mac OS X.  Using Parallels you can run OS X and OS X Server on a Mac running OS X.

Apple, under no circumstances, will license OS X to run on anything but a Mac.

Obviously, given that there are *Hackintoshes* out there, it would be fairly trivial for VMWare et al to virtualize OS X, but Apple just won't allow it.

Comment: You can also use VMware Fusion, and OS X Server runs on VirtualBox.