# Having Mac OS X on a XEN virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, mac-osx, xen, virtual-machines, mac-osx-server

Is it possible to have Mac OS X guest on a XEN host?

If yes, how?

There are difference for Mac OS X Server?

In particular I'm interested in the installation of a testing Mac OS X Server inside a XEN domU, being the host a Debian linux server in the case that this would matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See these other near duplicate questions: http://serverfault.com/questions/4046/virtualizing-os-x, http://serverfault.com/questions/3665/how-to-run-os-x-leopard-or-tiger-in-windows, http://serverfault.com/questions/32031/running-mac-os-x-on-hyper-v, among others all with the same answer. You aren't legally allowed to.

Comment: Sorry, the question didn't show up in the list of similar questions.

Comment: @chealion: Apple and many other computer companies would like you to think you aren't legally allowed to anywhere, but it really depends on what legal jurisdiction you reside in (and where the virtualisation is being done).  in many countries/states, shrink-wrap licenses and EULAs are as legally binding as a pretty-please request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your license for MacOS X only allows it to be run on Apple hardware. Only MacOS X server allows for virtualisation. Both [vmware](http://blogs.vmware.com/vmtn/2008/01/virtual-leopa-1.html) and [Parallels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Server_for_Mac) have products which support this.

It is possible to run MacOS non server in other virtualisation systems however it is not legal to do so. If you ran linux on the bare metal of a Apple peice of hardware you may be able to get Xen to run MacOS server legally.

Comment: As I specified I'm interested to actually virtualize Mac OS X Server, so I think I can do it legally ... the question is, now, how do the job with XEN ... is it possible?

Comment: @AlberT - Virtualizing on non-Apple hardware is not permitted by the EULA of Mac OS X Server. The EULA of Mac OS X (Client) does not permit virtualization.

Comment: EULA restrictions on usage are not legally binding or enforceable in all jurisdictions.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. I'd like an answer. If you don't know, then zip it.

Comment: Yeah, avoiding the question saying '...EULA...'. What if I run XEN on a mac mini, would this help you answer?

Comment: You can install Xen on a modern mac without issue. This is even more incorrect now then it ever was.

Answer (score 2):

Theres no known efforts for xen. Primarily because most people who use xen are running it exclusively on linux/x86/amd hardware. BUT other OSS projects, namely 'qemu' and 'virtualbox' have been working at this. It's likely that many of the technical issues you would have to overcome are similar. See: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2076&sid=3f507d8a7d8194f37b6dd8a089c919f5

Comment: Id suggest switching over from xen to Linux Kernel Virtial Machines (kvm). kvm do support os-x with patch here: http://alex.csgraf.de/self/?part/projects&folder/Qemu%20OSX&type/&project/projects&parameters/id=Qemu%20OSX

and here:  http://d4wiki.goddamm.it/index.php?title=Howto:_Mac_OSX_on_KVM

Comment: You should add your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Useful links:

---

https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM

https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM

https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts

---

Mojave:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#===========================================================================
# Works only with the official image available in the Mac App Store.
# Make sure you download the official installer before running this script.
#===========================================================================

hdiutil create -o /tmp/Mojave.cdr -size 8000m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J
hdiutil attach /tmp/Mojave.cdr.dmg -noverify -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia  --volume /Volumes/install_build --nointeraction
hdiutil detach "/Volumes/Install macOS Mojave"
hdiutil convert /tmp/Mojave.cdr.dmg -format UDTO -o /tmp/Mojave.iso
mv /tmp/Mojave.iso.cdr ~/Desktop/Mojave.iso
rm /tmp/Mojave.cdr.dmg
```

Catalina:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#===========================================================================
# Works only with the official image available in the Mac App Store.
# Make sure you download the official installer before running this script.
#===========================================================================

hdiutil create -o /tmp/Catalina.cdr -size 8000m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J
hdiutil attach /tmp/Catalina.cdr.dmg -noverify -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia  --volume /Volumes/install_build --nointeraction
hdiutil detach "/Volumes/Install macOS Catalina"
hdiutil convert /tmp/Catalina.cdr.dmg -format UDTO -o /tmp/Catalina.iso
mv /tmp/Catalina.iso.cdr ~/Desktop/Catalina.iso
rm /tmp/Catalina.cdr.dmg
```

Download the Installer App to you /Applications folder on Mac.
Once you have the ISO your halfway there!